# azureAD refreshtoken expires in 14 days

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have a long running application (many days/weeks). Is there anyway to get OAuth access that is not tied to the 14 day refresh token expiry? No matter what I try I lose access in 14 days. It would put a huge burden on our users to have to re-authenticate every N days.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure AD Refresh tokens have a *sliding* expiry of 14 days, up to a maximum of 90 days.](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/03/20/azure-ad-token-lifetime/) That is, as long as you use the refresh token in those 14 days, you will get a new refresh token valid for another 14 days. So your users would only need to re-enter credentials every 90 days.

That being said, for long running applications, the [Client Credentials Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) may be more suitable. This uses Application Permissions rather than Delegated Permissions (so you may need to change the permissions in the Azure portal). If you really need to make your calls as a particular user it may not work in your case.